# Using of angularjs in asp MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, design-patterns

We are developing an ASP MVC 5 application.
In Our dataBase we have a list of 700 companies.
The aim of this application is to display an index view to list all this companies.
there is also a link to display the details of each company.

Do you think that angularJs is good for such as web site?

If it is the cas how can i combine between MVC and angularJs?

When i have to use angularJs rather than using jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Whether you use AngularJs or not, the thing you described would take a few hours to implement. Why don't you try out both, with AngularJs and without it?

Comment: My point is, for trivial tasks as such as yours, it's not worth to think about it. You're literally wasting time. And it seems you lack some experience with ASP.NET MVC/WebApi. Try out a few things and see how things go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you think that angularJs is good for such as web site?

   Your requirement looks trivial and for such requirement either Angular Js or ASP.NET MVC would be good. I dont see much trade-off here.
   Please note that, from ASp.NET MVC to Angular JS, its a paradism shift - essentially you are moving from server centric MVC to client centric MVC architecture.
   Ofcourse you can use both (Angular JS + ASP.NET MVC) building an application, but if you are going angular way, Angular JS + Web API would be your best bet.
2. If it is the cas how can i combine between MVC and angularJs?

   Please look at http://josephjefferson.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/merging-asp-net-mvc-and-angularjs-routing/
3. When i have to use angularJs rather than using jquery?

   answer to this question needs couple of blog post :)
   In simple words, you can say
   AngularJS is a (MVC) framework (and jQuery is a hig-level library), hence Angualr JS enjoys all sort of MVC benefits
   AngularJS code is more testable, you can write unit test code  (using jasmine) and end-to-end test using protractor
   AngularJS supports many many many excellent features like two-way binding, directives, routing, dependency injection etc... those you wont get in jQuery.

Comment: tyhanks for responding, can you, please,  explain me what do youmean by  Angular JS + Web API would be your best bet.

Comment: what I mean is on client side you can use Angular JS and on server side you can use WebAPI(http://www.asp.net/web-api). ASP.NET Web API is restful. You can access WebAPI from angualr JS either using $resource or restangular(https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). This way you can have neat separations of concerns and you would establish a beautiful architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a mallet to pound the back of a hammer to drive a nail. there is no feasible reason to use ASP.NET MVC over angular.js even though i live and breathe angular. It seems you want the binding that angular provides which can easily be achieved with AJAX + jquery in A.MVC5